# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExpection from an existing SQLite database table

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having an error with calling from one of my tables in my database.

Using:

```
public Cursor getTable(String table, String where) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


        qb.setTables(table);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, null, where, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }
```

And:

```
public Armor(Cursor generalItems, Cursor armorItems){
        id = generalItems.getInt(0);
        name = generalItems.getString(1);
        armor = armorItems.getInt(2);
        slot = armorItems.getInt(3);
        bonusStat = armorItems.getInt(4);
        bonusAmount = armorItems.getInt(5);
    }
```

This works:

```
currentZone.c1.setChest(new Armor(db.getTable("items", "_id = 2"), db.getTable("armor", "itemid = 2")));
```

I am doing basically the exact same thing with my Weapon class, but I get this error:

```
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rpgengine/com.example.rpgengine.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at com.example.rpgengine.Weapon.<init>(Weapon.java:16)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at com.example.rpgengine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-29 00:50:08.426: E/AndroidRuntime(14696):    ... 11 more
```

I assumed there was an error in my database, and I checked the table - it seems correct to me.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the suspect call, and the function itself:

```
currentZone.c1.setWeapon(new Weapon(db.getTable("items", "_id = 1"), db.getTable("weapons", "itemid = 1")));
```

and

```
public Weapon(Cursor generalItems, Cursor weaponItems){
        id = generalItems.getInt(0);
        name = generalItems.getString(1);
        hand = weaponItems.getInt(2);
        damage = weaponItems.getInt(3);
        bonusStat = weaponItems.getInt(4);
        bonusAmount = weaponItems.getInt(5);
    }
```

The error is in the weaponItems cursor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first check whether ur table has data or not

Comment: Does this  query `Cursor c = qb.query(db, null, where, null,
                null, null, null);` run fine

Comment: The screenshot shows the data in the table.  The query executes, but I believe it is returning an empty table, because the error is in trying to access where the cursor is pointing, not when I actually make the cursor.

Comment: Have a look at Weapon.java line 16 and see what MainActivity.java got at line 81. Maybe you need to check first if the cursor's size is greater than zero before executing your other codes.

Comment: From error, it looks like your query returns empty cursor and from empty cursor you are trying to get row values that's why you are getting this error. so please check your returned cursor first. Hope it Helps!!

Comment: I assumed it was an empty cursor problem, the issue I'm trying to sort out is why it is empty.  It should be able to get values from the weapons table - there is one in there and I'm using the correct itemid to find it.

Comment: `Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` - your cursor has no rows!

Comment: I know, that was the issue.  I figured out the problem - the database was updated since I first used it in the program, so it kept the saved on database installed in the apk each relaunch.  I changed the name of the database in Eclipse and it worked.